# AJAX POST Receives 404 Error

Tags: python, ajax, post, flask, http-status-code-404

Trying to use AJAX to POST to my Python script `testing.py`. Whenever I try the POST, I receive the following error.

`POST http://localhost:5000/testing.py 404 (NOT FOUND)`

I'm using Flask to serve up my website. Why is this a 404 error, and how do I get `localhost` to serve my python script?

Comment: Sure testing.py is in the correct folder?

Comment: Is `localhost:5000` your Flask server? What routes did you define? `404` means that `/testing.py` is not a valid registered route in your Flask server.

Comment: If your file is called `testing.py` then *that is **just** the filename*, not the routes defined in Flask.

Comment: How do I allow it to run the script on the `localhost` then?

Comment: `localhost:5000` is my Flask server. `/testing.py` is a Python script.

Comment: I understand that. How do I get it to not be a 404?

Answer (score 0):

somewhere you should have a file called app.py,(but you can call it testing.py if you want) inside should be at least:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/testing') # you can probably even put testing.py here
def testing():
    vars = request.args
    return ','.join(map(str,vars))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

then

```
python app.py # or testing.py
```

then you can send your POST to `http://localhost:5000/testing`
and it will print any posted parameters to the browser